# how to find Regular expression named groups

Tags: regex, vb.net

What will the pattern for this line

```
\\input var: x(length),y(height),z(width)
```

I want to know named group of variables( like in this x,y,z) and named group of meaning of particular variable( Like in this length,width,height)

I tried the pattern for this text line

```
\\input var: x(length),y(height),z(width)

[\/\/\binput\b\s?\bvar\b:\s](\w+)\((.*?)\)\,?
```

I am only able to get group(1).value as x
                      group(2).value as length

How i will find other values like y , height, z, width

Comment: What flavor are you using? Tell us what language you are using so that we can help you!

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191014/how-to-regex-replace-named-groups

Comment: i saw this post but i didn't get it as my requirement is different. What will be the pattern for finding the group for words that are written in bracket (hello world). There can be multiple brackets in text.

Comment: You've got mismatched slashes in your input and regex, right at the start. Are you trying to parse information in code comments or should it be looking for backslashes?

Comment: I have made the changes in my question. Kindly look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution, I've used two regular expressions, one to get the inputs out of the original string, and then another to get your inputs and their meanings out of the result.

```
Dim textToParse As String = "\\input var: x(length),y(height),z(width)"

' Regex matches the start of the string and zero or more input(meaning) portions
Dim extractInputsSectionRegex As New Regex("\\\\input\s*(?<variable>var):\s*(?<inputs>(\w+\(\w+\),*\s*)*)")
' Regex matches an individual input and meaning and returns the captures in named groups
Dim extractIndividualInputsRegex As New Regex("(?<input>\w+)\((?<meaning>\w+)\)")

' Match the input string to extract inputs and meanings
Dim initialMatch As Match = extractInputsSectionRegex.Match(textToParse)

If initialMatch.Success = True Then

    ' Extract inputs and meanings
    Dim inputsSection As String = initialMatch.Groups("inputs").Value

    ' Match one or more input(meaning) portions
    Dim inputMatches As MatchCollection = extractIndividualInputsRegex.Matches(inputsSection)

    If inputMatches.Count > 0 Then

        ' Loop through each match found
        For Each inputMatch As Match In inputMatches

            ' Extract input and meaning
            Dim input As String = inputMatch.Groups("input").Value
            Dim meaning As String = inputMatch.Groups("meaning").Value

            ' Display
            Console.WriteLine("Input: " & input & ", meaning: " & meaning)

        Next

    End If

End If
```

Tested using the given input and the following strings:

```
\\input var: vol(volume),a(area)
\\input var: x(length), y(height), z(width)
```

Comment: If the meaning is multiple words then what will be the change in  Dim extractIndividualInputsRegex As New Regex("(?<input>\w+)\((?<meaning>\w+)\)") this line. example like \\input var: x(length in cm), y(height in cm), z(width in cm)

Comment: Well you're looking for a word character then an optional space. And this could happen more than once, so we can change the meaning group to `(?<meaning>(\w*\s*)+)`. `*` means zero or more times and `+` means one or more times.