# find regular expression named group

Tags: regex, vb.net

In my previous question [how to find Regular expression named groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396462/how-to-find-regular-expression-named-groups/19399664#19399664), I asked the regular expression for pattern

```
//input var: x(length),y(width),z(height)
```

If pattern will be changed like

```
//input var: x(length in cm),y(width in cm),z(height in cm)
```

Then what will be the regular expression for this?

what will be the change in this line

```
Dim extractIndividualInputsRegex As New Regex("(?<input>\w+)\((?<meaning>\w+)\)")
```

I tried

```
Dim extractIndividualInputsRegex As New Regex("(?<input>\w+)\((?<meaning>.*)\)")
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think you should stop with what you're doing and start learning regex. You may start [here](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/) or [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or maybe from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx). That way, you could at least try something useful without reaching for SO for every single "feature" you need.

Comment: @HamZa i learned. First i am trying by myself.

Comment: if you "learned" then you would have known that throwing a `\s` somewhere with some modification would have suited your needs

Comment: @HamZa I am not able to solve this. That's why i asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim extractIndividualInputsRegex As New Regex("(?<input>\w+)\((?<meaning>[\w\s]+)\)")
```

The `(?<meaning>[\w\s]+)\)` will match a combinations of space and word characters inside the `(` and `)` which should be enough.

[Regex Hero Demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=bf9a3c3c-e56f-4970-8bd4-6c365cdd1bc5)

Comment: @user2194838 I think it is working, check the demo link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<input>\w+)\((?<meaning>\w+) in (?<unit>\w+)\)
```

Shown on regexr: http://regexr.com?36oss

Or, if you want all three words in *meaning* group, try:

```
(?<input>\w+)\((?<meaning>\w+ in \w+)\)
```

Shown on regexr: http://regexr.com?36osv

Comment: I have to read all three words in one group

Comment: Ok, and do you always have the pattern *measure **in** unit* ? If yes, I added the case. If no, try sniffer's one.

Comment: yes, but the unit can be different. example tr(total travel between loads),st(stance in degree)

Comment: Ok, so you will want to use sniffer's one, mine is too specific.

Comment: @user2194838 +1 would be anyway appreciated :)

Comment: @Teejay here you go +1